# StackExchange App

Tags: discussion

I saw many questions over the stackechange app. Officially there is no Stackexchange App as we all know. But I recently discovered an app [StackMate](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/stack-mate/9nblggh0jf49) on Store. Not officially created nor has a title of StackExchange but it does possesses all the features you'll need. Best SE app on WP store yet. I'm using it and very happy with that. So can we answer to those questions with reference to this app or it will be wrong since it is not the official one? And if it is not wrong then can we standardize an app(not necessarily this one)? So that whole community would be united on a single app rather than having numerous unofficial apps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, go ahead and answer with a link and description of that app. I think as Windows Phone users we're all used to having unofficial apps ;)

Comment: So can we standardize an app ? So that whole community would be united on a single app rather than having numerous unofficial apps?

Comment: What do you mean by "standardize"? Make one app the official one? You'll have to contact the Stack Exchange team directly about this. Also check out the [existing questions about this on Stack Exchange Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=windows%20app).

Comment: @User5 In my opinion, there is no need for standardizing one app. Stack Exchange sites always welcomed with multiple opinions provided they are actual solutions. If required in an answer you can link multiple **quality** 3rd party apps. Multiple answers or an answer with multiple app links is welcomed provided they are helpful.

Comment: Got it. thanks!